# How to integrate togglz with spring-boot + jersey

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, togglz

My application is a Spring Boot + Jersey web app. I followed this [official tutorial](http://www.togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html) to integrate togglz with my Spring Boot application. I added the dependency `togglz-spring-boot-starter` to my project. But I always get below missing bean error when launching the Spring Boot application. According to the togglz spring-boot guide, it says this dependency should add all the missing beans into the application. What am I missing here?

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'togglzEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/togglz/spring/boot/autoconfigure/TogglzAutoConfiguration$TogglzEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.togglz.core.manager.FeatureManager]: : Error creating bean with name 'featureManager' defined in class path resource [org/togglz/spring/boot/autoconfigure/TogglzAutoConfiguration$FeatureManagerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'featureManager' defined in class path resource [org/togglz/spring/boot/autoconfigure/TogglzAutoConfiguration$FeatureManagerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: How did you configure the `FeatureProvider`? You have to define a `FeatureProvider` bean or set the `togglz.feature-enums` application property. See also http://www.togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html section Auto Configuration.

Comment: He's already said he read that page, and that page says nothing about configuring a FeatureProvider for non-enum setup. It says `Alternatively, or additionally, the togglz.feature-enums application property can be provided to create features from one or more enum classes. You can also provide features through an explicit FeaturesProvider` - the page implies that this is only necessary if you use the enum, not the default setup.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out the issue, I have to add below code on the spring boot config class:

```
@Bean
public FeatureProvider featureProvider() {
    return new EnumBasedFeatureProvider(AppFeatures.class);
}
```

Comment: Correct. As I mentioned see http://togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html Auto Configuration for details.

Comment: yes, but I didn't where to add this code. I added it in a wrong place.

Comment: Yes it's a normal Spring bean :-)